# Simple File Upload for FuelPHP

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, fuelphp

Does anyone have experience of uploading a series of files to a web server with FuelPHP?

My current setup adds content to a database from a Form, but I'd like to process images at this point too - so basically move them to my web server when submitting a form.

Is this simple to do?

I have my 'action_add()' method in my controller, but not sure how to update it to loop through all my file fields and move files.

```
public function action_add()
    {
        $val = Model_Article::validate('add_article');

        if ($val->run())
        {
            $status = (Input::post('save_draft') ? 0 : 1);

            if ( ! $val->input('category_id'))
            {
                $category_id = null;
            }
            else
            {
                $category_id = $val->validated('category_id');
            }

            $article = new Model_Article(array(
                'user_id' => $this->user_id,
                'category_id' => $category_id,
                'title' => $val->validated('title'),
                'body' => $val->validated('body'),
                'published' => $status,
            ));

            if ($article->save())
            {
                Session::set_flash('success', 'Article successfully added.');
            }
            else
            {
                Session::set_flash('error', 'Something went wrong, '.
                    'please try again!');
            }

            Response::redirect('articles/add');
        }

        $this->template->title = 'Add Article';
        $this->template->content = View::forge('articles/add')
            ->set('categories', Model_Category::find('all'), false)
            ->set('val', Validation::instance('add_article'), false);
    }
```

My Form:

```
<h2>Add an Article</h2>
<p>Publish a new article by filling the form below.</p>

<div class="options">
    <div class="option">
            <?php echo Html::anchor('articles', 'View Articles'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <?php echo Html::anchor('categories/add', 'Add a Category'); ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php echo $val->show_errors(); ?>
<?php echo Form::open(array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')); ?>

<?php $select_categories = array(null => 'Uncategorized'); ?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
<?php $select_categories[$category->id] = $category->name; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<div class="input select">
    <?php echo Form::label('Category', 'category_id'); ?>
    <?php echo Form::select('category_id', e($val->input('category_id')), 
        $select_categories); ?>
</div>

<div class="input text required">
    <?php echo Form::label('Title', 'title'); ?>
    <?php echo Form::input('title', e($val->input('title')), 
        array('size' => '30')); ?>
</div>

<div class="input textarea required">
    <?php echo Form::label('Body', 'body'); ?>
    <?php echo Form::textarea('body', e($val->input('body')), 
        array('rows' => 4, 'cols' => 40)); ?>
</div>

<div class="input textarea required">
    <?php echo FORM::file('filename'); ?> 
</div>

<div class="input submit">
    <?php echo Form::submit('add_article', 'Publish'); ?>
    <?php echo Form::submit('save_draft', 'Save Draft'); ?>
</div>

<?php echo Form::close(); ?>
```

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: you just only want to move the image to a folder or save it in the datbase too? sorry if im a bit slow, and could you please post your form too please

Comment: Hehe, it's ok. Probably my description :) I'd like to move images to a folder on my web server. I'll then try to move the file names into the table in my database. Thank for any help you can give :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I can give you some instruction.

First [fuelphp upload documentation](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/upload/usage.html)

Hope it helps sorry if there are typos in it

```
public function action_add()
{
$val = Model_Article::validate('add_article'); //<-- maybe its just me but I never saw any similar to this in fuelphp sorry about this if I'm wrong

// if your form validation is okay than continue with everyhing else
if ($val->run())
{
    $article = Model_Article::forge();
    // Custom configuration for this upload
    $config = array(
        'path' => DOCROOT.DS.'foldername/tomove/your/images',
        'randomize' => true,
        'ext_whitelist' => array('img', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'),
    );

    Upload::process($config);

    // if a valid file is passed than the function will save, or if its not empty
    if (Upload::is_valid())
    {
        // save them according to the config
        Upload::save();

       //if you want to save to tha database lets grab the file name
        $value = Upload::get_files();  
        $article->your_file_input_name = $value[0]['saved_as'];
     } 

    $status = (Input::post('save_draft') ? 0 : 1);

    if ( ! $val->input('category_id'))
    {
        $category_id = null;
    }
    else
    {
        $category_id = $val->validated('category_id');
    }

         $article->user_id = $this->user_id;
         $article->category_i = $category_id;
         $article->title = $val->validated('title');
         $article->body = $val->validated('body');
         $article->published = $status;


    if ($article->save())
    {
        Session::set_flash('success', 'Article successfully added.');
    }
    else
    {
        Session::set_flash('error', 'Something went wrong, '.
            'please try again!');
    }

    Response::redirect('articles/add');
}

$this->template->title = 'Add Article';
$this->template->content = View::forge('articles/add')
    ->set('categories', Model_Category::find('all'), false)
    ->set('val', Validation::instance('add_article'), false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I'll try just now and report back to you :-)

Comment: `ErrorException [ Parsing Error ]: syntax error, unexpected ')'` on line 87: `$article->published = $status; ));`

Comment: Hi Levente, I'm *so* sorry for the delayed reply. Shortly after I replied to you, my net died. I'm in the office now and will give it a try at lunch today. Many thanks again - and sorry for the delay.

Comment: Hi Levente - I'm back, post-test :-)
Here is my error message: `OutOfBoundsException [ Error ]: Property "your_file_input_name" not found for Model_Article.

PKGPATH/orm/classes/model.php @ line 897` Any ideas?

Comment: For the record, the image did move :-D Thank you for this. Any ideas about the error message above?

Comment: dood... your_file_input_name<--- i just gave you this variable as an example, rename it with your file input name....

Comment: Aaaaaah. D'oh :-D So my file input name is 'filename'. Do I have to then create a 'saved_as' field in my 'articles' table to store this value? I promise, I'll leave you alone after this ;-)

Comment: no, if your input name is "filename" than rename this "your_file_input_name" to filename, and in the database where your article table is, create a row named "filename" and you are okay with the database save too

Comment: You're too good, Levente. I'd provide 2 green ticks if I could. Thank you!!